# How affect class who have static attributes

Tags: java

I want to know how deserilize a class who contain staic attributes from file because when I create an instance from project , I can't affect it to the global class

My Code : ( deserialize method doesn't work )

```
public class Project implements Serializable{

    private static  String name;
    private static  String site;
    private static  Table table;


public static  String getName() {
    return Project.name;
}

public static   void setName(String name) {
    Project.name = name;
}

public static  String getSite() {
    return Project.site;
}

public static  void setSite(String site) {
    Project.site = site;
}

public static  Table getTable() {
    return Project.table;
}

public static  void setTable(Table table) {
    Project.table = table;
}

// Serialize
public static  boolean  serialize(String path){
       try{

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path);
        Crypto.encrypt(Project.class, fout);
         return true;
       }catch(Exception ex){
           return false;
       }
   }

   public static boolean deserialze(String path){

       try{

          FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
          Project project = (Project) Crypto.decrypt(fin);// decrypt file
          Project.name = project.getName();
          Project.site = project.getSite();
          Project.table = project.getTable();
          return true;
       }catch(Exception ex){
           return false;

       }
```

Comment: If its static, the line `Project.name = project.getName();` is setting itself equal to itself.

Comment: yes I know this is the problem and I need an answer how to correct that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization works with objects — *instances* of classes.  But `static` fields aren't part of an instance.  So serialization doesn't touch them.

You're not actually serializing an instance of your `Project` class, though.  You're serializing the class object itself, which is an instance of the `java.lang.Class` class.  I can see why you'd think that might store your static fields, but it doesn't: a class object is for [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), getting information *about* the class.  It doesn't actually hold the class's data; the static fields in the class are not fields of the `Project.class` object.  AFAIK, serializing a class object is generally not a useful thing to do.

Your fields look like they probably shouldn't be `static` anyway, because they hold information that should be different for each project.  Right now, you have a single name that's shared across *all* projects, and a single site, and a single table.  You could run `new Project()` fifty times and have fifty distinct objects, but there's no way to make them *different* from each other.  Your program has no way to represent two projects with different names.

My advice:  take out all the `static` keywords, change your static field references (e.g. `Project.name`) to instance field references (e.g. `this.name`), create an instance of your class (e.g. `Project project = new Project()`) and set its fields, and serialize *that*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to implement `java.io.Serializable` interface remember that when you deserializing `transient` or static `fields` they most likely gonna have default value (null for Object types).
Static field also get default value if there are no objects in the scope (otherwise it get initialized with the value that is defined for an existing object).